# Purpose of the snort´s rules

Tags: snort, intrusion-detection

So for example, why i need `scan.rules` when there is something like sfportscan preprocessor ? Is it because preprocessor can not detect all the activities and so there is detecting engine using rules with well known signatures of network attacks trying to find match ? But there are also preproc rules, so i am bit confused now. So preprocessor use their own rules and then there are normal rules in case none of this preproc rules found the match ?

Thank you for answer.

Comment: Preproc just help activities of the rules through packet reassembly, decode, and sorting of src and dst ip structures, ETC. Refer to http://seclists.org/snort/2008/q2/26

Comment: But do preprocessor generate alert by itself or do they need rules and when are preprocessor.rule use ?

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor rules are used to enable or disable (or change) events triggered by preprocessors. See [snort manual](http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node18.html).

The file scan.rules has nothing to do with the sfportscan preprocessor. It is meant as a container file to hold rules that detect possible scanning events. This eases the exclusion/inclusion of rules for users that don't need the whole ruleset.